# Compute sum from another table in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I need to create model in Django for the following :

```
Invoice table -> invoice_id, order_id, unit_price, num_units
                  1, 1, 10, 5
                  1, 2, 10, 5
                  2, 1, 10, 5
                  2, 2, 10, 5
                  3, 3, 10, 5
                  3, 1, 10, 5
                  3, 2, 10, 5

Invoice Summary table -> invoice_id, sum
                          1, 100
                          2, 100
                          3, 150
```

How should my Model look like for the above tables in Django?

I tried:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
      inv_id = models.IntegerField()
      order_id = models.IntegerField()
      unit_price = models.IntegerField()
      num_units = models.IntegerField()

class Summary(models.Model):
      invoice_id = 
      sum = invoice_id total sum i.e ( unit_price * num_units ) for invoice_id
```

How will my Summary Model look like such that I get correct result for a particular Invoice id?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Foreignkey for connect summary model with Invoice model. If you will not import your invoice id, you don't need to inv_id because django generate id field automatically.

```
class Summary(models.Model):
    invoice = models.Foreignkey(Invoice,on_delete=models.CASCADE) #Cascade means if your invoice is deleted, related summaries deleted, too.
    sum = models.IntegerField()
```

You can use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/) for calculate sum field. But don't forget, signals isn't fired on update method.Basically, you can create a temple field as result that contains multiplication of num_units and unit_price, after you can sum with aggreagate method this temple field.
You can use current field value with [F](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) expression.

in your signals.py:

```
def calculate_sum_of_invoice(sender, **kwargs):
    invoice_id = kwargs.get('instance').id
    summary = Invoice.objects.filter(id=invoice_id).annotate(
result=F('unit_price') * F('num_units')).aggregate(Sum('result'))['result__sum'])
    Summary.objects.update_or_create(
    invoice_id=invoice_id, defaults={"sum": summary}


post_save.connect(calculate_sum_of_invoice, sender=Invoice, dispatch_uid="invoice-save-signal")
```

Comment: But how come sum will be multiplication of unit_price and num_units for a particular invoice id ? @kamilyrh

Comment: In database design, we should always try not to store things that can be computed.. And by definition, a sum is a computation. Try using [python property](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html?highlight=property#property) instead.

Comment: @Ibris yes, but he has one to many relation on summary and invoice. He wants to store sum of multiple records on summary

Comment: yes @kamilyrb i'm only getting the data for the 1st data with invoice id and not all data with same invoice id

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Sum

sum = Invoice.objects.all().values('unit_price').annotate(
    average_grade=Sum('unit_price') * F('num_units'))
```

change your model.py

```
class Summary(models.Model):
    invoice = models.Foreignkey(Invoice,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sum = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: unit_price and num_units are multiplied to get total sum @justin

Comment: In database design, we should always try not to store things that can be computed.. And by definition, a sum is a computation. Try using [python property](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html?highlight=property#property) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to keep **sum** in `Summary` table, you don't have to create a separate table, you can simply add **sum** field in **Invoice** table and then you can use **Signal** for calculating and storing sum.

However, here is proposed solution, if you want it in this way:

```
class Summary(models.Model):
    invoice = models.OneToOneField(
        Invoice,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )

    sum = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**using [Post Save Signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#post-save)**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.db.models import Sum


def update_invoice_summary(sender, instance, **kwargs)
    try:
        obj = Summary.objects.get_or_create(invoice=instance)
        obj.sum += instance.unit_price * instance.nums_unit
    except Summary.DoesNotExist:
        obj = Summary(instance, instance.unit_price * instance.nums_unit)

    obj.save()


post_save.connect(update_invoice_summary, sender=Invoice)
```

Comment: In database design, we should always try not to store things that can be computed.. And by definition, a sum is a computation. Try using [python property](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html?highlight=property#property) instead.